# Keeping a struct as a value type - What types can I use / return?

Tags: c#, struct, types

I want to store a lot of little items (well, a few thousand) of 3 or so byte values, so I am thinking of using a struct.
What I am unsure about is how to keep it as a value type, for example, if I just store the 3 bytes as bytes and override ToString(), GetHashCode() and Equals(), it will stay a value type, right?
But what about if I want to return the 3 bytes as a list (return, not store!), so I do

```
public List<byte> GetValues
    {
      get
        {
             return new List<byte>(3) { byte1, byte2, byte3 };
        }
    }
```

..but would this now mess it up? 
Would part of this struct's data now be on the heap?

I did read somewhere about this stuff, but I can't remember where and can't find it again.

Thanks for any advice you can give me.

Richard

Comment: The property you've declared creates a new object on the heap, but it doesn't change your struct into a reference type.  A struct is a value type, period.

Comment: Technically, from what I see you want to have only one instance of each small object. You can keep all of the possible bytes inside a "storage" list, and remember indexes for them. Each time a new (not existing in storage) byte appears, you add it, and remember the index for it.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's just a property - the list is created when the property is accessed, but that's all. You haven't declared any extra *fields* within your type.

Even if you *did* declare a field of type `List<byte>`, your type would still be a value type - *all* structs are value types - it's just that one of the fields would have a value which is a reference. That's relatively uncommon, but not unheard of.

Comment: Jon, it's not so uncommon at all.  `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, where either type argument is a reference type, comes to mind.

Comment: @phoog: Well, I did only say *relatively* uncommon :) (`List<T>.Enumerator` springs to mind too.)